# Auto-untar/gunzip a multilayer tarball in Win XP/7

Tags: tar, gunzip, self-extracting

I review a disgusting ball of knowledge each day that I'd like to think up a way to organize more automatically. The structure looks like this - Parenthesis show the number of files of that type in that subdirectory:

> .tar
>
> > .tgz (2)
> >
> > > .tar
> > >
> > > .tgz (3)

This equates to ~20 total untar/gunzips to extract the raw data. File is 73MB and I have little say over its structure at this point, so I just have to deal with it.

Any ideas on how to make this prettier? I can use Linux-based systems for now, but the goal is to make this self-extracting on Windows platforms.

Comment: I was hunting around the web to learn about symbolic links and found the beginning of my own answer (on http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/#toc18): How to untar an entire directory full or archives?

.tar: for i in `ls *.tar`; do tar xvf $i; done
.tar.gz: for i in `ls *.tar.gz`; do tar xvfz $i; done

Comment: still need help converting this idea to Windows... so post away.